# Unusual behaviour of the VBA Listbox addition

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a VBA program to run add the list of items from visible range of the excel sheet. See the code below:

```
Dim LR, LRR As Integer
Dim FilterArea As Range
Dim oneCell As Variant
Dim FiltCount As Integer
LR = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2.Cells.AutoFilter
UserFrom3.ListBox1.Clear
FiltCount = 0

'AutoFiltering the FilterArea
With Sheet2.Range("A2:N" & LR)

    If (UserFrom3.ComboBox3 <> "") Then
        FiltCount = 1
        .AutoFilter _
        Field:=4, _
        Criteria1:=UserFrom3.ComboBox3
    End If

    If (UserFrom3.ComboBox1 <> "") Then
        FiltCount = 1
        .AutoFilter _
        Field:=5, _
        Criteria1:=UserFrom3.ComboBox1
    End If

    If (UserFrom3.TextBox1 <> "") Then
        FiltCount = 1
        .AutoFilter _
        Field:=8, _
        Criteria1:="*" & UserFrom3.TextBox1.Text & "*"
    End If
End With



If FiltCount = 1 Then
    With UserFrom3.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 7
        .ColumnHeads = False
        .ColumnWidths = "50,35,50,50,75,89,100"


        For Each oneCell In Sheet2.Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .AddItem CStr(oneCell.Value)
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = oneCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = oneCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = oneCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = oneCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = oneCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
            .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = oneCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        Next oneCell

    End With
End If

End Sub
```

The above code is working fine whenever I give a valid input to the UI. It returns the result. When There is nothing to filter.. i.e., When the filter result is zero. and zero rows are visible except the headers (in excel and listbox).

However After this zero rows visible situation, I am getting an error in next search. Listbox loads all the unwanted data except my ranges(i.e., it shows Values from other ranges) and shows error on code

```
.List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = oneCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
```

Error message is "Run time error 1004 - Application defined or object defined error. "

Can someone please tell what is the issues?

Comment: What's in the cell when it errors?

Comment: This will sound stupid, but *have you tried turning it off and back on?*  The autofilter, that is... .AutoFilterMode=False prior to turning on with .AutoFilter, to see if the issue is with removing the autofilter before finding new search criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following code.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Sheet2
If Ws.FilterMode Then
    Ws.ShowAllData
End If
```